# save file without save dialog

Tags: c, winapi, file-io

I have 3 global variables:

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;

TCHAR FileName[1024];

TCHAR Title[1024];
```

In WM_CREATE, I fill the information for ofn:

```
static TCHAR filter[] = TEXT("Bitmap Files (*.BMP)\0*.bmp\0") \
    TEXT("All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0\0");

ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.hInstance = NULL;
ofn.lpstrFilter = filter;
ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
ofn.nMaxCustFilter = 0;
ofn.nFilterIndex = 0;
ofn.lpstrFile = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFile = 1024;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 1024;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.lpstrTitle = NULL;
ofn.Flags = 0;
ofn.nFileOffset = 0;
ofn.nFileExtension = 0;
ofn.lpstrDefExt = TEXT("bmp");
ofn.lCustData = 0;
ofn.lpfnHook = NULL;
ofn.lpTemplateName = NULL;
```

In WM_COMMAND with `case ID_FILE_SAVE:`, I have

```
            case ID_FILE_SAVE:
                if (!SaveAsBmpDialog(hwnd, FileName, Title))
                    return 0;
                SaveAsBmp(FileName);
                return 0;
```

where `SaveAsBmpDialog` is

```
static bool SaveAsBmpDialog(HWND hwnd, TCHAR *fileName, TCHAR *title) 
{
ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
ofn.lpstrFile = fileName;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = title;
ofn.Flags = NULL;

return GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
}
```

It works fine to save HDC to a Bitmap file (which can be open).

But in WM_CHAR with `wParam == 'p'`, I have

```
SaveAsBmp(FileName);
return 0;
```

I use this function when `SaveAsBmpDialog` is called at once before, so `FileName` is a full-path already.

But I get a Bitmap file, which can not be open. (Even if I delete the file first, it creates the file, but still cannot be open). The file size is as before, so I think `WriteFile` in `SaveAsBmp` works.

I don't understand why it doesn't work without `GetSaveFileName(&ofn)` in `WM_CHAR`.

What I want is to save HDC to a exist file without save dialog.

ps: In `SaveAsBmp`, I have

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(FileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

DWORD dwBytesWritten;

//SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
WriteFile(hFile, &fileHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, &info.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + info.bmiHeader.biClrUsed * sizeof(RGBQUAD), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, pPixels, (int) info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Comment: These functions have return values for you to see whether they succeed or fail. If you're ending up with a bad file, chances are at least one of them is failing.

Comment: But the difference in these two case is calling SaveAsBmpDialog, which is just to fill the information about full-path. Since I have already the path, it should work when calling SaveAsBmp. This is why I feel it is strange.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the comment "cannot be opened." ?? Do you mean it is not recognized as a valid BMP file, or that the file cannot be accessed due to sharing permissions (i.e. someone else claims they already have it open) ? I hope the reasons for this question are obvious.

Comment: `GetOpenFileName()` has no effect on `CreateFile()`, unless you are creating the file using a relative file path since `GetOpenFileName()` can change the calling process's working directory. But that is the only effect.

Comment: I meant `GetSaveFileName()`, not `GetOpenFileName()`, but what I said still applies.